# Convert daltons (Da) to molar mass (g/mol)

Tags: concentration, units

This is probably a stupid question...

In converting Da to molar mass (g/mol),

Since 1 Da = 1 g/mol, is it logical that 64,776 Da = 64,776 g/mol or am I missing an intermediate calculation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, you are right. There is a complication though, when converting masses obtained from mass spectrometry (which is the usual context of the unit Dalton) to molar mass, and that is isotopic abundance. For a few elements, there is only one naturally ocurring isotope, but most are a mixture of isotopes with different weights. This has to be accounted for when calculating molar mass, meaning you need the molecular formula.

Comment: Thank you. This is for HbA1c (glycated hemoglobin). I am not sure the molecular formula, but I have been told this: "Looking back to the definition of the measurand reported by the IFCC Working group on the standardization of HbA1c (i.e. HbA1c - N-(1-deoxyfructosyl)-haemoglobin-ß-chain) and considering that HbA is composed by two alpha chains, two beta chains and four hemes (MW 64,452 da), the MW of HbA1c can be estimated to be 64,776 daltons (i.e. Mw of HbA - mw of 2 water molecules + mw of 2 molecules of glucose)." If you could help me interpret how this translates to the molecular formula?